# How to create a page periodically using wiki bot

Tags: php, mediawiki, bots

My prime aim is to get a page , parse the text and create a subpage periodically depending on the text. To get a page ,create and login, i have the following code .Php version-5.3.3,server:localhost

```
private function login($username, $password, $wiki) {
      $response = $this->postAPI($wiki, 'api.php?', 'action=login&lgname=' . urlencode($username) . '&lgpassword=' . urlencode($password));
      if ($response['login']['result'] == "Success") {
          //Unpatched server, all done
      } elseif ($response['login']['result'] == "NeedToken") {
          //Patched server, going fine
          $token = $response['login']['token'];
          $newresponse = $this->postAPI($wiki, 'api.php?', 'action=login&lgname=' . urlencode($username) . '&lgpassword=' . urlencode($password) . '&lgtoken=' . $token);
          if ($newresponse['login']['result'] == "Success") {
              //All done
          } else {
              echo "Forced by server to wait. Automatically trying again.<br />\n";
              sleep(10);
              $this->login($username, $password, $wiki);
          }
      } else {
          //Problem
          if (isset($response['login']['wait']) || (isset($response['error']['code']) && $response['error']['code'] == "maxlag")) {
              echo "Forced by server to wait. Automatically trying again.<br />\n";
              sleep(10);
              $this->login($username, $password, $wiki);
          } else {
              die("Login failed: " . $response . "\r<br />\n");
          }
      }
  }
```

Function to get a page is:

```
  public function get_page($page, $wiki = "")//get page's content
  {
      $response = $this->callAPI($wiki, 'api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=' . urlencode($page) . '&rvprop=content');
      if (is_array($response)) {
          $array = $response['query']['pages'];
          $array = array_shift($array);
          $pageid = $array["pageid"];
          return $response['query']['pages'][$pageid]['revisions'][0]["*"];
      } else {
          echo "Unknown get_page error.<br />\n";
          return false;
      }
  }
```

I have a problem with login. I always get Forced by server to wait. Automatically trying again regardless my password and id is correct. Infact the URI works properly if given manually.And if i try to create a page or get a category, i get the following error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at serverlocation/Phpwikibot.php:188) in serverlocation/includes/WebResponse.php

Can some one help me with this issue?

Comment: Please use supported bot software and then let us know. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code

Answer (score 0):

You say "localhost", so you have server-side access and you should be using the internal PHP API, not the web API. In particular, to edit a page you can use `maintenance/edit.php`. See [a real world example](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/OPUP/browse/production/files/misc/scripts/characterEditStatsTranslate) I used for some Wikimedia wikis:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
  # Stuff
  # Fetch stuff
  echo -e $stuff
} | php edit.php --user "FuzzyBot" \
    --bot --summary "Update stats" "Meta:Babylon/Translation_stats"
```